# How to register Interface<T> with T is an interface in Structuremap

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, structuremap

I have an interface

```
    IFinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>
```

and the `FinancialMarketRepository` is

```
    FinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>
```

When I register that by StructureMap with code

```
    x.For(typeof(IFinancialMarketRepository<>)).Use(typeof(FinancialMarketRepository<>));
```

I got a message

> "No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type `'IFinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>'`
>
> There is no configuration specified for `IFinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>`

I also try with code:

```
    ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(expression => expression.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
        scanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IFinancialMarketRepository<>));
        scanner.WithDefaultConventions();                  
    }));
```

But the error message still exist.

**Update**

Here is code that I define x:

```
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>{
   x.For(typeof(IFinancialMarketRepository<>)).Use(typeof(FinancialMarketRepository<>));
});
```

Comment: Without having used StructureMap I'm going to guess it's because `FinancialMarketRepository<>` isn't an object that can be created.

Comment: Please explain more, I don't understand your idea

Comment: You can't write the code `var x = new FinancialMarketRepository<>()`. It seems likely that the `.Use(...)` type should be creatable. I might be wrong, but it seems like a fair guess.

Comment: Do you think you could provide the code for declaring `x`? I could have a bit of a play with the code then.

Comment: I added StructureMap to my test code but I can't find an `ObjectFactory` class anywhere in it. Can you please provide the all the code I need?

Comment: I used StructureMap version 3.1.3, the `ObjectFactory` belong to this version

Comment: I've NuGetted version 4.1.2.386. It doesn't appear to be there. Have they changed the object model that much?

Comment: My project is using version  3.1.3, so I can't upgrade to new new version :(

Comment: It does look like they have deprecated `ObjectFactory` in the latest version. I've trued this code `var c = new StructureMap.Container(x => x.For(typeof(IFinancialMarketRepository<>)).Use(typeof(FinancialMarketRepository<>)));` and `c.GetInstance(typeof(IFinancialMarketRepository<string>))` works fine. Can you post your definition of `FinancialMarketRepository<T>`?

Comment: `IFinancialMarketRepository<T>` with T is an interface, It isn't object. In my project, it is `IFinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>`, `IFinancialMarket` is an interface

Comment: And class FinancialMarketRepository is defined `public class FinancialMarketRepository<TEntity> : Repository<BaseDbContext, TEntity>, IFinancialMarketRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, IFinancialMarket{}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108499/discussion-between-v-hoang-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 0):

You effectively have this code:

```
public class Entity { }

public interface IFinancialMarket { }

public interface IFinancialMarketRepository<T> { }

public class FinancialMarketRepository<TEntity> : IFinancialMarketRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity, IFinancialMarket { }
```

And, with StructureMap, you're trying to create an instance of `IFinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>` - which StructureMap has been told to instantiate `FinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>`.

Now, if I try it with this code:

```
var fmr = new FinancialMarketRepository<IFinancialMarket>();
```

...the compiler tells me:

> The type 'IFinancialMarket' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'FinancialMarketRepository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IFinancialMarket' to 'Entity'.

You're basically trying to create a type that doesn't conform to the generic constraint. That's why it is failing.